# Calculating the joint area of two circles centered by two coordinates with 1 kilometer radius

Tags: python, buffer, shapely

The coordinates are (116.437017,39.91525) and (116.437591,39.91548) for example in Gaode Map (https://lbs.amap.com/tools/picker).

I want to draw two circles using `Point(lon, lat).buffer()` in shapely to calculate the joint area in km^2 of the two circles.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from itertools import combinations


a=Point(116.437017,39.91525).buffer(km*1)
b=Point(116.437591,39.91548).buffer(km*1)
shapes=[a,b]
overlap=cascaded_union(shapes)
print(overlap.area)
```

But I do not know how to convert 1 kilometer in this coordinate system in Gaode Map. My goal is to calculate many joint areas with circles generated by many coordinates. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these points are in UTM 50 China zone, you can use following code for calculating corresponding overlapping area (by the way, unary_union method is preferred instead cascaded_union):

```
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import unary_union, transform
from itertools import combinations

a = Point(116.437017,39.91525)#.buffer(km*1)
b = Point(116.437591,39.91548)#.buffer(km*1)

wgs84 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:4326')
utm = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:32250')

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(wgs84, utm, always_xy=True).transform
a_utm = transform(project, a)
b_utm = transform(project, b)

a_buff = a_utm.buffer(1000)
b_buff = b_utm.buffer(1000)

intersection = a_buff.intersection(b_buff)
intersect_area = intersection.area

print(intersect_area/1e6, "km2")
```

By using above code, overlapping area is 3.026025245899957 km2 for a,b buffers. This area (in pink color) can be observed in following picture. Points are about 55 meters apart.

[image]